# Using docker container as a proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, reverse-proxy, iptables, devops

In general, I am trying to use a docker container as a HTTP proxy for other docker containers inside the same network overlay. 
let's call this proxy container Gateway. This Gateway suppose to change the HTTP requests it receives to a HTTPS request, and forward it to the outside world, assuming the gateway is configured with all the required CAs certificates.

Now lets get specifics, I'm using docker swarm and services + replicas, the gateway provide some api on port 80 and containers uses the Gateway's service name + port 80 in order to request this api (which doesn't relate to the proxy I need)e.g:

*http://gateway:80/api/logout*

I want to use this port also for the proxy, which means other containers can send HTTP requests to some IP (not DNS) on port 80, and this requests will go through the gateway, and than, the gateway will look at the http request and see that this message is not for "him", and it will execute http**S** (on port 443) request to the actual external server.

I can't use the solution of Docker's proxy in below link:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Because this solution of HTTP proxy is only for already running proxy, and not a dockerized one. (if I use it, docker will not be able to get the images from repo, because it will look for a proxy which doesn't exists, because docker itself didn't bring up the Gateway container yet).

So, that brings me to the problem. how will I forward internal containers requests to the gateway without using the Gateway service name.

I think *iptables* is the only option, but how? I can't use Gateway IP because Gateway is a replicas on 3 VMs and and the IP changes, in any case, any container which sends *http://some_external_server_ip:80/some_api* will need to somehow go through gateway.

**TLDR**

can I do something in the iptables (with docker chains and PREROUTING chain maybe) to forward all packets (sent by containers in their overlay network) on port 80 into a service container named Gateway, while ignoring the destination ip? (only identify the packet by the port and forward it to a specific contianer)

Hope this is clear... =)

Comment: I don't know if I completely understood your question but jwilder/nginx-proxy worked well for me forwarding to containers based on request. 
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy

Comment: I don't have a problem in implementing or using existing proxy. i have a problem in using proxy container which proxy all internal container's packets (in internal network) to that proxy container. (the problem is that when using docker swarm u need to specify service name in order to push the message to the service, and in a proxy, u don't do that, u put the external server, and somehow the Proxy server will get the message.

Comment: And why is a existing proxy no solution for you? You can use Traefik, Nginx, Haproxy (in a container) etc... Exactly for that use case. So you config something like: http://myswarm/myapi/somethingmyapicando

Comment: there is no problem in using an existing proxy like nginx or whatever. as i already said twice (see my comment above you), this is not the issue i describe. You need to know docker internal containers communication in order to understand. My conatiners use their own overlay network, and I want to proxy some containers using 1 specific container. (note that host node can't go in to the network, and I do not open ports to the outside world). I only say that Docker HTTP Proxy solution (in link above) is talking about proxy external(!!!) communication. read my solution it will give u some insight.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found my answer with a little of tcpdump investigation.

When using docker's HTTP_PROXY configuration in this link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy
it isn't working on containers inside the same network because the link above describe a proxy for external communication (proxy to outside the overlay network).

So, assuming *Container A* is the proxy container, and *container B* is some other container which run HTTP requests to some external ip, and assuming both of those containers are located on the same docker's overlay network (some internal network of docker). Than, in order for HTTP requests coming out of *container B* will go through *container A*, we will need to define environment variable in *container B*:

1. **http_proxy** - this environment variable will hold the name and the port of the proxy container for example: *http_proxy=containerA:8080* 
   **NOTE:(*containerA* is the service name of *container A*)**
2. **no_proxy** - this environment variable will hold all the ips which shouldn't go through the proxy.
   for example, you wouldn't want that inner network communication of *container B* will go through *container A*, e.g if *container B* want to talk to *container C* on HTTP, assuming they are both on the same overlay network, then, you want them to "talk" freely without *container A* act as a proxy. in this case, u will put the sub-net of the overlay network (which all containers are located in) in the no_proxy environment variable (and also localhost access) in my case it is something like this: ***no_proxy=10.0.0.0/24,localhost,127.0.0.1***.

When those 2 environment variables are set on *container B*, then all **outside** HTTP communication of *container B* will go through *container A*

NOTE: "outside communication" means using some external IP which is not known for docker service names.